# Changing AutoPlay options

Tags: windows-xp, autoplay

Is there a way to remove or change the order of the options and/or programs that pop up when you plug in a CD, USB stick or the like?

I don't know what it's called exactly, but it's that menu or option dialog that appears when you insert a new CD or a USB stick or some other media and is right on the second when you're determined to click on something else.

I really would wish for the "Open folder and view files" option and some others to be on top, and not buried under a ton of others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey there!  You're looking to deal with XP's "AutoPlay" feature.

[Here's some info](http://www.winbookcorp.com/_technote/WBTA20000846.htm) on using it the 'regular' way.

Additionally, you can change the items in the list via the registry by altering the following keys:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoplayHandlers\Handlers\`

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoplayHandlers\EventHandlers\`

[Here's a bit of info and a utility](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/autoplayhandlers.htm) that may help you out with doing that.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Beautiful ! Clear and to the point!